# Extract a portion of a string in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with ~200,000 rows and I need to extract a portion of a string from one of the columns. I have tried `split` and `str_split` and not getting at what I need.

I need to cut/split/explode on the **/** forward slash and only return the first field.

From the following sample I need only subdomain.domain.org

**subdomain.domain.org**/Site/SiteXYZ/Users/Usergroup

I have tried:

```
splitA <- str_split(my_data$OrganizationalUnit, pattern = "/", simplify = TRUE)
```

which returns a dataframe with multiple columns, one for each string between the delimiters

```
head(splitA)
     [,1]                   [,2]   [,3]      [,4]    [,5]
[1,] "subdomain.domain.org" "Site" "SiteXYZ" "Users" "Usergroup"
```

and

```
splitB <- str_split(my_data$OrganizationalUnit, pattern = "/", n = '2', simplify = TRUE)
```

which returns a dataframe with multiple columns, one for each string between the delimiters

```
head(splitB)
         [,1]                   [,2]
    [1,] "subdomain.domain.org" "Site/SiteXYZ/Users/Usergroup"
```

and

```
splitC <- **str_split**(my_data$OrganizationalUnit, pattern = "/", n = '1', simplify = TRUE)
```

which returns a dataframe with one column, that looks like the original

```
head(splitC)
         [,1]
    [1,] "subdomain.domain.org/Site/SiteXYZ/Users/Usergroup"
```

My end goal is to either:

- Extract this string as part of larger queries
- Add a column with this field
- or add this as a column upon csv import

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,

-Jacob

Comment: Hey, a quick solution that just comes to my mind would be to use gsub and simply :
`splitA <- gsub("/.*$","",my_data$OrganizationalUnit)`
But I cannot give you any details about performance in contrast to other functions... But with this you could hand over the entire column of your strings and put that to an additional column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, if I understood right what you are after. As stated in the help file of `?str_split()`, the `simplify` argument means:

> "If FALSE, the default, returns a list of character vectors. If TRUE returns a character matrix."

If you are dealing with a character vector of domains, you can use `simplify=TRUE` and extract the first column of the matrix with `(...)[, 1]`. In any case, it is more efficient to use a combination of `str_sub()` and `str_locate()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- c("subdomain.domain.org/Site/SiteXYZ/Users/Usergroup",
       "othersubdomain.domain.com/Site/SiteXYZ/Users/Usergroup",
       "yetanothersubdomain.domain.com/Site/SiteXYZ/Users")

str_sub(x, start = 1, str_locate(string = x, "/")[, 1]-1)
# -1 otherwise / is kept in resulting string

str_split(x, pattern = "/", n = '2', simplify = TRUE)[, 1]
```

```
[1] "subdomain.domain.org"           "othersubdomain.domain.com"      "yetanothersubdomain.domain.com"
```

#### In a data.frame

If it is a column in a data.frame, you can use mutate() from {dplyr}:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(domain = x, 
                y = rnorm(length(x))
)

df_extracted_domain <- df %>% mutate(
    domain_suffix = str_sub(x, start = 1, str_locate(string = x, "/")[,1]-1)
)
```

in case you are not familiar with tidyverse and specially the pipe operator `%>%`, just read it as "and then". so the above line you read:

take `df`, "and then" mutate `df` (by adding a new variable, called domain_suffix). The mutated data.frame is assigned to a new object (or overwritten, if you call them the same)

### benchmarking

```r
y <- rep(x, 1e3)

bm <- rbenchmark::benchmark(
    str_split = {
        str_split(y, pattern = "/", n = '2', simplify = TRUE)[,1]
    },
    str_sub = {
        str_sub(y, start = 1, str_locate(string = x, "/")-1)
    }, 
    replications = 1000
)
```

```
#        test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1 str_split         1000     1.4      7.1       1.4    0.011          0         0
# 2   str_sub         1000     0.2      1.0       0.2    0.000          0         0
```

Comment: This is getting me closer, it does get me the output I am looking for.  
TESTING <- str_sub(my_data$OrganizationalUnit, start = 1, str_locate(string = my_data$OrganizationalUnit, "/")[,1]-1)

Now I just need to learn how to add it as a column to the original dataframe.

Comment: edited the answer a bit to focus on the data.frame part. Doesn't that work? (the relevant part is `df_extracted_domain <- df %>% mutate(
    domain_suffix = str_sub(x, start = 1, str_locate(string = x, "/")[,1]-1)
)`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, it works!
`library(tidyverse)
x <- my_data$OrganizationalUnit

str_sub(x, start = 1, str_locate(string = x, "/")[, 1]-1)
# -1 otherwise / is kept in resulting string

str_split(x, pattern = "/", n = '2', simplify = TRUE)[, 1]


df <- tibble(domain = x, 
             y = rnorm(length(x))
)

df_extracted_domain <- df %>% mutate(
  domain_suffix = str_sub(x, start = 1, str_locate(string = x, "/")[,1]-1)
)
my_data$extractedDomain <- df_extracted_domain$domain_suffix`